# How long is a typical malware signature?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, yara

I read in Peter Szor's Art of Computer Virus Research and Defense that, in the past, a 16-byte malware signature was sufficient to 16-bit detect malware, but that longer signatures are necessary for 32-bit malware. I am wondering how large the typical signature is for modern malware.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the length of the address bus or registers directly corelates to the length of a malware signature. It's far more likely that malware was simpler back then, and thus required shorter signatures to detect it. As software (malware included) increases in complexity, so do signatures.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that being the case. I'm still interesting in knowing how long a viable signature is nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

What antivirus vendors mean when they use the term signature is not digital signature/hash/checksum. A malware signature here is really best described as a short program written in a domain specific language that can classify whether a file is or isn't malware. It does not necessarily have a specific length to it, but rather depends on the complexity of distinguishing it from legitimate software.

Further reading: [How do antiviruses scan for thousands of malware signatures in a short time?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/30362/2755)